# How do I cheat death in Hardcore?

Tags: diablo-iii

I keep finding myself losing to the Nightmare Butcher. I was wondering if anyone out there had any tips I could use to keep me alive in sticky situations.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's okay to ask and immediately answer your own question, you don't have to create two separate accounts for that.

Comment: Are you looking for general strategies, or just how to beat the Butcher?

Answer (score 3):

I tend to avoid HC bossfights until I get to a point where everything up to the fight is basically a cakewalk (except for champs with stupid affix combos. Then I just reload :) )

Obviously, good gear is also important, but in The Butcher's case it's also a matter of learning the fight. He telegraphs his grab and his charge very strongly, so those shouldn't be a problem. Maybe practice on an SC character until you can kill him in your sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

I find that fighting the butcher is *much* easier with multiple people, since he only focuses on one person at a time *(which gives you time to run away and heal up)*, and since *anyone* can grab a health-well to heal everyone.

So, fight him with some friends, or if you don't have any, join a public game on the previous quest.

Answer (score -2):

Well, besides just being a smart player (having potions, never attacking enemies with less than half health, making sure you upgrade your gear, kite enemies as much as possible) I found that this little trick can get you out of a boss fight that you know you are going to lose.

The idea is to exit the game before you die.

Comment: I don't think "exit the game" is a valid strategy for surviving Hardcore.  Also, I have removed your video, as it was completely unneccessary.

Comment: Technically, if your character doesn't die, and you are using a mechanic built in to the game... it is a valid strategy.

Comment: I didn't mean for the whole video to show up, just the link. I think the link is valid. It shows the trick that I was talking about.

Comment: The *only* thing the video imparts to the strategy is "exit the game".  There's no need for even the link.